# How do you export an interface into global namespace - angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a file with defined interfaces I'd like to share with my app's global namespace. My first attempt to do this was that I imported the `interfaces.ts` file into my `app.module.ts` and placed the interface into the `exports` array, but types/interfaces cannot be used in this way, so I thought of a few questions related to this small issue.

Does `app.module.ts` need to be involved for exporting to the global namespaces?

Is there a different way to do it (probably a native javascript way)?

If `app.module.ts` is required to do this, how do I import an interface in a way that my `app.module.ts` shares it with the rest of my app, so that I wont have to constantly `import` it in my components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the global namespace here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html

```
/*~ Note: If your global-modifying module is callable or constructable, you'll
 *~ need to combine the patterns here with those in the module-class or module-function
 *~ template files
 */
declare global {
  /*~ Here, declare things that go in the global namespace, or augment
   *~ existing declarations in the global namespace
   */
  interface String {
    fancyFormat(opts: StringFormatOptions): string;
  }
}
```

Beware though:

> This pattern is somewhat dangerous due to the possibility of runtime conflicts, but we can still write a declaration file for it.

Comment: I added the ```declare global {}``` with all my defined interfaces into my app module. This works, but it would be nice to have the interfaces in a file to which I can then "put" into the ```declare global {}``` block. Is there a way to to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a `SharedModules` for everting that you want to use in the entire application more than one place according to the Angular official [document](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules). In this `SharedModules` you can have different directory app structure for all common things such as `Models`, `Services`, `Interceptors`, `Pipe`, `components` and etc.

Then Use this module on your main `app.module.ts` and `import` what you need.
For more information study this helpful & quick guide on [PluralSight](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-shared-modules-in-angular).